# Обработка html страницы с помощью BeautifulSoup и вывод всех ссылок, которые есть на этой странице

Tags: python, html, ссылки

Задача следующая: Необходимо обработать ссылку https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping с помощью BeautifulSoup и вывести все ссылки, которые есть на этой странице, в том порядке как они встречались по одной в строке.

**Под ссылкой понимается содержимое аттрибута href тега a.**

Вам могут быть полезны методы find_all для супа (он позволяет найти все теги на странице), метод has_attr для тега (проверяет есть ли такой атрибут у тега) и доступ к атрибуту тега по аналогии со словарем.
Написала код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping')
html = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Вроде все работает, но тестирующая система не принимает ответ. Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в том, что многие ссылки имеют не традиционную форму, то есть например /wiki/File:Question_book-new.svg и начало ссылки в виде https://en.wikipedia.org отсутствует.
Попробуйте изменить цикл так:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if link.has_attr("href"):
        link = link.get("href")
        if "http" in link:
            print(link)
        else:
            print("https://en.wikipedia.org" + link)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько целесообразен данный подход, но я делал так:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping')
html = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
# Просто заменил все относительные ссылки на полные
html = html.replace('href="/', 'href="https://en.wikipedia.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что надо было не выдергивать страницу напрямую из Википедии, а сохранить ее html код как txt и работать уже с ним.
Больше никаких заморочек не было. Тестирующая система реально поняла под ссылкой содержимое аттрибута href тега a.
Код видоизменила следующим образом:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = open('test3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if link.has_attr("href"):
        s = link.get('href')
        print(s)
```

Комментаторам выражаю свою глубокую признательность. Они внесли правки, исходя из "реальности". Если бы в реале приходилось править, то именно их методами я бы воспользовалась. Но кто же мог предположить, что просто сама тестирующая система вредничает.